# Eclipse: missing requirement E4 RCP patch when installing properties editor

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I tried to install properties editor plugin from http://propedit.sourceforge.jp/eclipse/updates in `Help` -> `Install new software`. but won't installed. I got the following error:

[image]

I think my eclipse dosen't have E4 RCP patch. where can i get it? how can i install e4 RCP patch?

thank you in advance.

**EDIT** : I'm working on STS 3.6.3. the error message is

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software currently installed: Spring Tool Suite 3.6.3.201411281415-RELEASE-e44 (org.springsource.sts.ide 3.6.3.201411281415-RELEASE-e44)
Missing requirement: E4 RCP Patch (bugzillas 445122) 1.0.0 (org.eclipse.e4.rcp.R441patch.feature.group 1.0.0) requires 'org.eclipse.e4.rcp.feature.group [1.3.100.v20140909-1633]' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Spring Tool Suite 3.6.3.201411281415-RELEASE-e44 (org.springsource.sts.ide 3.6.3.201411281415-RELEASE-e44)
To: org.springsource.sts.package.feature.group [3.6.3.201411281415-RELEASE-e44]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Spring Tool Suite Package 3.6.3.201411281415-RELEASE-e44 (org.springsource.sts.package.feature.group 3.6.3.201411281415-RELEASE-e44)
To: org.eclipse.e4.rcp.R441patch.feature.group 0.0.0
OK
```

Comment: can you share some more details and steps how to reproduce this? versions of STS that you use to get to this problem?

Comment: Go to Help -> Install new software. Install properties editor plugin from  http://propedit.sourceforge.jp/eclipse/updates. I got the above error.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, with Groovy/Grails Tool Suite 3.6.3.SR1
Build Id: 201501121239
Platform: Eclipse Luna SR1 (4.4.1), trying to upgrade the AWS toolkit. 
I tried to install the 445122 patches, but Eclipse thinks they're incompatible with the AWS upgrade.

Comment: Exact same for 3.6.3 SR1 - appears only fix is to re-install to 3.6.4.

Answer (score 2):

Please deselect "Contact all update sites during..." and try again to install the add-ons. That should help.

This problem should be solved with STS 3.6.4 being released soon on top of Eclipse Luna SR2.

Comment: I'm now getting the exact same error when I try to update any plugins.  I tried deselecting "Contact all update sites during...", but no luck.  If there is a JIRA issue for this I can supply more details on all the troubleshooting steps I've attempted.

Comment: and please feel free to comment on this issue tracker item: https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-4080 - more details how to reproduce this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The patch is available from the `http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.4/` update site. Use 'Install New Software' to install it from there.

Comment: I've installed eclipse 4.4.1 patches for bug 445122, but I got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error while trying to install Spring Roo. I tried installing the patch from http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.4/ but that didn't work either. The solution that worked for me,

1. Download Eclipse Luna SR 2.
2. Install STS from the Eclipse market place.

I didn't hit the bug again.

Comment: I think this answer is the only way to go. There is no 'org.eclipse.e4.rcp.feature.group [1.3.100.v20140909-1633]' available from any of the repositories.