# AWS Toolkit plug-in to Spring tool suite Error

Tags: java, maven, amazon-web-services, spring-tool-suite

I trying to install aws-toolkit http://aws.amazon.com/eclipse but i get the following error:
Below are some details on my STS version
Spring Tool Suite

```
Version: 3.6.3.SR1
Build Id: 201501121239
Platform: Eclipse Luna SR1 (4.4.1)
```

I also have Maven-plugin installed if this is anyhow related to maven.
Thanks for ya time !

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software currently installed: Spring Tool Suite 3.6.3.201501121239-SR1-e44 (org.springsource.sts.ide 3.6.3.201501121239-SR1-e44)
Missing requirement: E4 RCP Patch (bugzillas 445122) 1.0.0 (org.eclipse.e4.rcp.R441patch.feature.group 1.0.0) requires 'org.eclipse.e4.rcp.feature.group [1.3.100.v20140909-1633]' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Spring Tool Suite 3.6.3.201501121239-SR1-e44 (org.springsource.sts.ide 3.6.3.201501121239-SR1-e44)
To: org.springsource.sts.package.feature.group [3.6.3.201501121239-SR1-e44]
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Spring Tool Suite Package 3.6.3.201501121239-SR1-e44 (org.springsource.sts.package.feature.group 3.6.3.201501121239-SR1-e44)
To: org.eclipse.e4.rcp.R441patch.feature.group 0.0.0
OK
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across this error while analyzing this:
[Eclipse: missing requirement E4 RCP patch when installing properties editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28847975/eclipse-missing-requirement-e4-rcp-patch-when-installing-properties-editor)

I hope that deactivating the option "Contact all update sites during..." while installing the AWS tooling helps here as well.

And this should also be solved once STS 3.6.4 is GA.